# Gitlab CI - build image and pass to next stages?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to setup a pipeline using Gitlab CI and PHP/Symfony project. My `.gitlab-ci.yml` file should contain 3 stages:

- Build - build the image, setup the database, install composer etc
- Tests

  - Unit tests
  - Other tests (code quality, security checks)

I have it working as it should at the moment, but only by running the build steps alongside each test - this means I'm repeating the same build steps twice and it's taking longer than it should.

I know that GitLab allows you to build a Docker image and store it in the project, but for the time being, is there a mechanism to build the Docker image, store it (as an artifact?), and then pass it onto the test stages so they don't need to repeat the build?

Answer (score 7):

Although using the registry to store the image is indeed the recommended way there is an answer to your question:

In the `build` stage save the image as a file:

`docker save -o myimage.tar myimage:build123`

Define `myimage.tar` as an artifact, use `depends_on` in the follow-up stage jobs and load the image there:

`docker load -i myimage.tar`

Comment: Thanks - I've hit a snag in that my image is based on php7.3-fpm which doesn't contain the `docker` binary, so it seems the `docker save` command won't run. I note that you can have `docker:dind` as a service, but I'm struggling to get everything glued together. Do you know of any more complete examples I could look at?

Comment: @fistameeny There is a complete, coded example in the [DigitalOcean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-docker-images-and-host-a-docker-image-repository-with-gitlab#step-3-%E2%80%94-updating-gitlab-ci-yaml-and-building-a-docker-image). Combine this with Stefan's answer above and the [GitLab docs on artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/job_artifacts.html), and you should be done.

Comment: @fistameeny Using sysbox makes sense, see [GitLab Runner Deploys Jobs in System Containers](https://blog.nestybox.com/2020/10/21/gitlab-dind.html#gitlab-runner-deploys-jobs-in-system-containers)

Comment: i think the downside to doing it this way is you don't know if your `docker push` was properly saved to the repo.